# Find the locus of the intersection between lines with parameter

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

I have $A(3,0)$, $B(k,2)$, $C(k,5)$, $k$ is a variable.

I need to find the locus of the intersection between AC and BO. (O is the origin).

What I tried is to find the equation of both AC and BO in terms of $k$.

I got

$$y_{AC} = \frac{5}{k-3}x - \frac{15}{k-3}$$
$$ y_{BO} = \frac2kx$$

I found the intersection between both lines (i.e. $y_{BO} = y_{AC}$).

I found that

$$x = \frac{15k}{3k+6}$$

In other words, the locus would be in that case

$$y = \frac{15x}{3x+6}$$

This however is not a line (and it should be). It is not the answer either.

What did I do wrong? I can show more steps of my solution if you need.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the answer $y=5-x$?

Comment: @Jens Yes, or as it is written in the book, $x+y-5=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that $$\tag{1}x = \frac{15k}{3k+6}$$

[or simpler

$$\tag{1.5}x = \frac{5k}{k+2} \ \ ]$$

doe not imply $y = \frac{15x}{3x+6}$ because you can not say that $x$ and $k$ are the same.

You have to plug the expression of $x$ in (1.5) into relationship  $y=(2/k)x$, in order to get

$$\tag{2}y = \frac{10}{k+2}$$

(1.5)+(2) constitutes a parametric representation of the locus.

If you desire a cartesian representation, you need to eliminate parameter $k$, which is very simple by adding (1.5)+(2), giving:

$$x+y=5$$

which is the equation of a straight line.